# Creating WPF Validation error manually

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a UI with some controls in it bound to `Person` class. Whenever user enters a new information business logic need to check the database if such a person exist. If not I need to give message to user and mark that textbox like it has error(red frame around the box). My Question is can I do that on the getter or setter of the property that gives Validation error?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `IDataErrorInfo`  , you can do this as follows,

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (name == "Age")
            {
                if (this.age < 0 || this.age > 150)
                {
                    result = "Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150.";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

in XAML Binding as follows,

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource data}" Path="Age"
                    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"   />
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered kind of the same problem when learning to use Validations wit WPF
I found help through this [tutorial](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/05/wpf-adorners-part-3-ndash-adorners-and-validation.aspx), hope it can help you too!

Comment: -1 It is generally preferable *not* to leave such short answers with just a link in them on StackOverflow. You can find out more in the [Answering section of the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I will remove this downvote if/when you update your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this precision, I'm sorry I did that mistake.

Comment: We all learn something new every day. As I said, if you edit your post by adding some context from your linked tutorial, then I can remove my down vote... I can't physically remove it *until* you make an edit though - it's not possible.

Comment: That's not really what I was talking about, but I'll remove the down vote for your effort. If you take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252276/two-stackpanels-inside-another-stackpanel/19252369?noredirect=1#comment28501374_19252369), you'll see that I have provided a link to a page that could help the question author, but I have also copied some of it into the answer to highlight the relevant part. Please see the [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer_) section of the help pages for more information on this.

Comment: Thank you for the examples and taking the time to help meimprove my posts.

Comment: You're welcome. In StackOverflow, it is customary for experienced users to help newer users with these things, not just with coding matters.

Answer (score 0):

your VM should implement `IDataErrorInfo` and set `ValidatesOnDataError=True` in your Binding. Then you can validate in your ViewModel if such a person exists.