# Issue with Validation in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation

I have applied the validations of required field validation on the wpf textbox, using the  ***ValidationRule*** class. My code is :

```
public class RequiredField : ValidationRule
{
    private String _errorMessage = String.Empty;
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _errorMessage; }
        set { _errorMessage = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, this.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

And the XAML code is below :

```
<TextBox  Name="txtName"  MaxLength="50">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <myValidtaion:RequiredField ErrorMessage="Please enter Name." />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This seems to work fine. But the issue is that after i save the valid data in database and clear the database, this validation is fired again and validation message appears again.

How can I avoid this situation ?

Comment: Can you breakpoint in `Validate` and provide a call stack?

Comment: You mean clear the field, not the database I guess?  because if that is what you mean, it will treat it as a change, and hence validate it again... Kinda makes sense

Comment: @Noctis, i understand but want to prevent this.
Milie, call stack is having no big information 

REMTools.dll!REMTools.RequiredField.Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo) Line 27 C#

Am i missing anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common validation 'problem', but it is in fact the expected behviour of WPF validation... this also occurs when using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

Both of these validation methods will validate their specified properties whenever their values change, which is exactly what we want (most of the time).

I believe that the system is called predictive validation and it enables us to show the user what they have to fill in *before* they try to save. I personally believe that this is a better system than the old system of letting the user try to save fields with errors and then telling them *afterwards* that they have made an error.

Perhaps you can delay clearing the fields until the user clicks a `New` button, in which case the errors will only show up then?

UPDATE >>>

If you were to use the `IDataErrorInfo` interface, then you could add a `bool IsValidating` property to your data type classes that you could use to switch validation on and off. I don't have much time, so I found a post that implements this interface that I have adapted to demonstrate my point.

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int age;
    private bool isValidating = true;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public bool IsValidating 
    {
        get { return isValidating; }
        set { isValidating = value; }
    }     

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Age"];
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (IsValidating)
            {
                if (name == "Age")
                {
                    if (this.age < 0 || this.age > 150)
                    {
                        result = "Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150.";
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

> Adapted from the code in the accepted answer to [Creating WPF Validation error manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248100/creating-wpf-validation-error-manually/19248151#19248151) post

When you switch this `IsValidating` property to `false`, the property changes won't be validated:

```
person.IsValidating = false;
```

Comment: Hmmmm....But this will not be a good thing to delay the clearing of fields until user clicks on new button. I guess there should be some way around to get this fixed.